# DNS Email not forwarding issues

Tags: domain-name-system, email, godaddy, mx-record, email-server

So I setup JAMES successfully, and it works fine, if I send myself an email from gmail say, a@gmail.com sends to b@45.75.477.34 <- my ip. But when I do it for my domain name, it doesn't work, say b@abc.com. So I re-pointed all the mx(s) to my domain in godaddy. all the stmp, pop, inap goes to my domain now, yet, when I try to send it, gmail still fails. Can someone please help?

Comment: I think this should be moved to http://superuser.com/ , not StackOverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you JUST changed the DNS settings, you'll need to give them time to propogate.

Use a few tools like [this one](http://www.hscripts.com/tools/HDNT/dns-record.php) to see what DNS records have been propogated, and to make sure the records reflect what you expect them to be.